# I had a misunderstanding with my boss

Tags: resignation, mistakes

Since my schedule the past two years hasn't been the ideal, I've only worked three hours on Sundays. However, recently, I asked for additional hours, and they offered me more. Then, last week, I had a misunderstanding with my boss. I was supposed to work until 7 pm, but they cut my hours like they always do. So I went online to see if my boss had sent me an explanation. Instead, I saw a message in the app from my boss telling me to keep my schedule the same as before, which made me angry.

I was angry because I assumed, they didn't think I was qualified to work more hours than the other employees who had worked in the restaurant not too long ago,(I've worked for two years in the company). The following week, I gave a letter of resignation and worked my regular shift of three hours as before because of the message of my boss .

However, that was a misunderstanding on my part because the message sent by my boss was like August 19, and I didn't see the date on the message but only a notification. Today, since I thought my shift finished after 3 hours, I left the restaurant. But actually like I said the message sent from my boss was like 1 month ago and today I was scheduled 7 hours. I couldn't go back because it was too far from my house, and my boss contacted me because of it.

What should I do now that I'm feeling bad? I wouldn't have resigned, only when I thought they changed my schedule. I regret a little bit.

Comment: So you did a 7-hour shift when your boss expected you to do a 3-hour shift, and then you did a 3-hour shift when your boss expected you to do a 7-hour shift? Someone in this company needs to set up better communication.

Answer (score 9):

> What should I do now that I'm feeling bad? I wouldn't have resigned, only when I thought they changed my schedule. I regret a little bit.

You can speak with your boss and attempt to retract your resignation.  Let them know that there was a misunderstanding on your part and express your desire to continue working at the company.  This is no guarantee that your boss will accept you back but it is the best course of action if you want to continue working at this company.